# Conditional elif statement is not yielding the correct results

Tags: python, conditional-statements

The elif stament should print the log files and path that were not found in a search that I conduct. However, they yield every line that is searched in a single file (a plethora of info). What am I doing wrong?

```
 for line in fileinput.input(walk_dir(directory, (".log", ".txt"))):
      result = regex.search(whitespace.sub('', line))
      if result:
          template = "\nLine: {0}\nFile: {1}\nString Type: {2}\n\n"
          output = template.format(fileinput.filelineno(), fileinput.filename(), result.group())

          print output
          temp.write(output)
          break
      elif not result:
          template = "\nLine: {0}\nString not found in File: {1}\nString Type: {2}\n\n"
          output = template.format(fileinput.filelineno(), fileinput.filename(), result.group())

          print output
          temp.write(output)

  else:          
      print "There are no files in the directory!!!"
```

Actual Code:

```
 elif searchType =='2':
      print "\nDirectory to be searched: " + directory
      print "\nFile result2.log will be created in: c:\Temp_log_files."
      paths = "c:\\Temp_log_files\\result2.log"
      temp = file(paths, "w")
      userstring = raw_input("Enter a string name to search: ")
      userStrHEX = userstring.encode('hex')
      userStrASCII = ''.join(str(ord(char)) for char in userstring)
      regex = re.compile(r"(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII )))
      goby = raw_input("Press Enter to begin search (search ignores whitespace)!\n")


      def walk_dir(directory, extensions=""):
          for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
             for name in files:
                if name.endswith(extensions):
                   yield os.path.join(path, name)

      whitespace = re.compile(r'\s+')
      for line in fileinput.input(walk_dir(directory, (".log", ".txt"))):
          result = regex.search(whitespace.sub('', line))
          if result:
              template = "\nLine: {0}\nFile: {1}\nString Type: {2}\n\n"
              output = template.format(fileinput.filelineno(), fileinput.filename(), result.group())

              print output
              temp.write(output)
              #break
          elif result not in line:

              output = fileinput.filename()

              print output
              temp.write(output)
              break 

      else:          
          print "There are no files in the directory!!!"
```

Comment: why are you using `elif`? a simple `else` would suffice here.

Comment: In the `elif` block, (i.e. if `result` is False-ish), calling `result.group()` should raise an exception.

Comment: So it never enters the `elif` part? Can you show the regular expression you use and a sample of the content of one file?
@unutbu: true, but it doesn't seem to ever go there.

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because @unutbu is right, `result == None` when no match is found, so when you enter the `elif` block, `result.group()` should throw an exception.

Comment: `result` is either True or it's False...there's no middle case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over *every line* of every file passed to `fileinput.input(...)`, right? And you perform the `if` statement for every line. If the condition is true, then you `break`, but if the condition is false, you don't break, but write to `temp`. So for every line in `fileinput.input` that doesn't match the condition, you write a line to `temp` and print `output`. (Actually, the above is wrong -- see edit below.)

Also, `elif str(result) not in line:` will have strange results -- just use `else` as others have suggested. If `result` evaluates to false in this situation, then `result == None`, which means that `str(result) == 'None'`, which means that if a line contains `None`, then you'll have unexpected results.

**Edit**: Ok, actually, looking more closely at your actual code the above is wrong, strictly speaking. But the point remains -- `fileinput.input()` returns a `FileInput` object that in essence concatenates the files and iterates over every line in turn. Since in some cases you don't want to perform an action per line, but per file, you'll have to iterate over them individually. You could do this without `fileinput` but since that's what you're using, we'll stick with that:

```
for filename in walk_dir(directory, (".log", ".txt")):
    for line in fileinput.input(filename):
        result = regex.search(whitespace.sub('', line))
        if result:
            template = "\nLine: {0}\nFile: {1}\nString Type: {2}\n\n"
            output = template.format(fileinput.filelineno(), fileinput.filename(), result.group())
            print output
            break   # (assuming you only want to print the first result)
    else:
        ouput = fileinput.filename()
        print output
        temp.write(output)
        break
```

The way this works: for every file in the list, this prints the first match in the file, or prints the filename if no match was found. You can use `else` with a `for` loop in python; the `else` block at the end of the loop is executed if the loop is not broken. Since no match was found, the filename is printed.

If you wanted to print out *all* matches in a file, you could save the matches in a list, and instead of using `else`, you could test the list. Simplified example:

```
matches = []
for line in fileinput.input(filename):
    if searchline(line):
        matches.append(line)
if matches:
    print template.format(matches)
else:
    print fileinput.filename()
```

Comment: my feeble attempt is to search and match a user entered string in different .txt and .log files, and print the file in which the string was found and line number. Also, I wanted to print the files where the string was not found/matched. This seems simple enough, but I'm just bumping into all kinds of walls. It's difficult when you your knowledge of a language (Python) and its constructs is limited ....

Comment: @user, it's no problem. Actually part of what I said was wrong... update coming.

Comment: This helped to see where the problem was ... I'm dispatching with fileInput altogether. Thanks!